# How to decode RGB segmentation in one-hot tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, rgb, one-hot-encoding

I would like to transform an RGB segmentation mask in a [one-hot](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30215/what-is-one-hot-encoding-in-tensorflow) segmentation.

In particular, given an RGB segmentation mask **y** where each pixel is associated to a different colour according to its class, I want to translate it into a one-hot segmentation **y_oh**, where each class is on a different channel.

In other terms, **y** has shape NxMx3 (N=height, M=width, 3=channels); **y_oh** has shape NxMxC, with C=number of classes. The last axis is the class axis and has value 0 everywhere exception made for the index associated with the class to which the pixel belongs to.

I'm working on LIP dataset [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc9Grm.png), that has segmentation labels for 19 human parts (e.g. C=19). Segmentation maps look like this:

[image]

Thank you!
G.

**Reference:** 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc9Grm.png) Gong, K., Liang, X., Shen, X., Lin, L.: Look into person: Self-supervised structure sensitive learning and a new benchmark for human parsing. arXiv preprint
arXiv:1703.05446 (2017)

Comment: It would help if you explained what a one-hot vector is. This may be common knowledge in your field, but if you'd translate the question to: 'how to obtain RGB values from image' people would find the question easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated the question :)

Comment: Is it possible to build on results of processing image to a array using `from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array image = load_img('/content/Gc9Grm.jpg')
image_array = img_to_array(image)`.